# Browser Cache control: Different behavior among Internet Explorer and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser-cache, cache-control

I have been working on a problem to prevent serving cached server pages on click of browser back button. Went thru [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) and setting appropriate response headers (below) work, but there is inconsistent behavior between IE and chrome.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```

**IE:** 
Serves a 'Webpage has expired' once I go back to a page using back button

**Chrome:** 
Doesn't say page expired, and doesn't serve a cached page either, but does a new server request even on a back button - sort of like hitting refresh.

My question: Is this how they are meant to respond to the headers and is there a way to achieve a consistent result? The primary intention is to avoid serving cached pages on back button across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually I had it figured out. The behavior on Chrome was different because of a browser setting on Chreme Dev Toolbar to explicitly disable cache as in the screenshot below. And this caused the page to hit the server instead of showing a page expired.

If I disable this option, I do see the '*Confirm form re submission*' page.

[image: Chrome Dev toolbar]